# Exporting shapefile from RStudio

Tags: shapefile, r, export, rstudio

Please can someone show me how to export a file from R in the format of a shapefile in order to be used in GeosegregationAnalyzer (which requires a shapefile).

I have merged attribute data with the shapefile on R as shown below and want to export this new file called "Classmap01"

```r
Brismap01 = st_read("lsoa01/lsoa01.shp")

Class01 = read.csv("ClassData2001.csv")

Classmaps01 = merge(Brismap01, Class01, by.x="lsoa01cd", by.y="code")
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`sf`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/index.html) function for layer writing:

```r
st_write(Classmaps01, "Classmaps01.shp")
```

Answer (score 1):

To export as a .shp use below code:

```
writeOGR(out.df, dsn = '.', layer = 'poly', driver = "ESRI Shapefile")
```